# What's the difference using 'event' as parameter in these formats?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

There's an event handler function in my project, which takes 'event' as the only parameter.There's only one format working in the project.
E.g. If a line of `console.log` is added to the function body, it would be displayed only in the first format.

The framework is an internal one, based on React, also uses web components.

What are the difference between these formats?

All three formats have the same function body.

Format 1, working in my project:

```
public sendClickEvent = ({ event: e }) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // handler body
}
```

Format 2, not working in my project:

```
public sendClickEvent = (event: any) => {
   event.preventDefault();
  // handler body
}
```

Format 3, not working in my project:

```
public sendClickEvent(event: any): void {
   event.preventDefault();
  // handler body
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details? What does "not working" mean? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: Apparently the first argument is an object with a field named "event". What framework do you use?

Comment: I just added details to the question.

Comment: Please share **more** details, like a runnable example that triggers the behaviour

Comment: Please show the html that you attach `sendClickEvent ` event to it

Comment: And tag Typescript if that is what it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `sendClickEvent` is called with an *object*, which has a property named `event`. As a result:

```
public sendClickEvent = ({ event: e }) => {
  e.preventDefault();
```

works because `{ event: e }` destructures the `event` property from the object argument and puts the event into a variable named `e`. But

```
public sendClickEvent = (event: any) => {
   event.preventDefault();
```

won't work because the argument is an object wrapper around it, not the event itself. You'd need something like

```
public sendClickEvent = (obj) => {
   obj.event.preventDefault();
```

Since this is TypeScript, I'd also highly recommend not using `any`, since that effectively disables type-checking, defeating the whole purpose of using TypeScript. Figure out the exact type the function should be called with, and type the function as that, so that you don't have to use `any` anywhere. Perhaps something along the lines of

```
public sendClickEvent = ({ event: e }: { event: React.MouseEvent }) => {
  e.preventDefault();
```